# Do parameterized controllers/module only run once in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I'm using a loop controller in JMeter to iterate through some modules multiple times with different parameters. Inside the loop controller I have a beanshell sampler deciding what values to set the variables to depending on the loop iteration. Then there are several jp@gc Parameterized Controllers with modules inside of them. However, when I run the program it seems that only the modules intended to pause the script, debug samplers, and the beanshell sampler are actually running everytime. All of the other modules only run the first iteration. Is there a way to fix this, or a different controller to use maybe?

Edit: Did a little more testing by using a debug sampler. It seems that the code is going into the parameterized controller and running the debug sampler, but then it isn't going into the module controller and running what I need it to... I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. For some reason simple controllers only ever run once, even if they're in a loop. I couldn't find anything even mentioning this in my google searches, I just happened to try changing the simple controllers that were containers for my modules to parameterized controllers even though i didn't need the parameterization and the loop suddenly worked. I hope this can help anyone else that runs into this issue as I couldn't find any other solutions online.